# Avoid overflow when adding numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, integer-overflow, numpy-ndarray

I want to add numpy arrays with datatyp uint8. I know that the values in these arrays may be large enough for an overflow to happen. So I get something like:

```
a = np.array([100, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
a += b
```

Now, a is `[150 250  44]`. However, instead of an overflow I want values which are too large for uint8 to be the maximum allowed for uint8. So my desired result would be `[150 250 255]`.

I could get this result with the following code:

```
a = np.array([100, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
c = np.zeros((1,3), dtype=np.uint16)
c += a
c += b
c[c>255] = 255
a = np.array(c, dtype=np.uint8)
```

The problem is, that my arrays are really big so creating a third array with a larger datatype could be a memory issue. Is there a fast and more memory efficient way to achieve the described result?

Comment: [DIPlib](https://diplib.org)’s integer addition saturates. DIPlib functions work directly on NumPy arrays, and you can convert between its image type and NumPy arrays without copying the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a third array of dtype uint8, plus a bool array <s>(which together are more memory efficient that one uint16 array)</s>.

[`np.putmask`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html#numpy.putmask) is useful for avoiding a temp array.

```
a = np.array([100, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
c = 255 - b  # a temp uint8 array here
np.putmask(a, c < a, c)  # a temp bool array here
a += b
```

---

However, as @moarningsun correctly points out, a bool array takes the the same amount of memory as a uint8 array, so this isn't necessarily helpful. It is possible to solve this by avoiding having more than one temp array *at any given time*:

```
a = np.array([100, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
b = 255 - b  # old b is gone shortly after new array is created
np.putmask(a, b < a, b)  # a temp bool array here, then it's gone
a += 255 - b  # a temp array here, then it's gone
```

This approach trades memory consumption for CPU.

---

Another approach is to *precalculate* all possible results, which is O(1) extra memory (i.e. independent of the size of your arrays):

```
c = np.clip(np.arange(256) + np.arange(256)[..., np.newaxis], 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
c
=> array([[  0,   1,   2, ..., 253, 254, 255],
          [  1,   2,   3, ..., 254, 255, 255],
          [  2,   3,   4, ..., 255, 255, 255],
          ..., 
          [253, 254, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
          [254, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
          [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)

c[a,b]
=> array([150, 250, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

This approach is the most memory-efficient if your arrays are very big. Again, it is expensive in processing time, because it replace the super-fast integer additions with the slower 2dim-array indexing.

EXPLANATION OF HOW IT WORKS

Construction of the `c` array above makes use of a numpy broadcasting trick. Adding an array of shape `(N,)` and array of shape `(1,N)` broadcast both to be `(N,N)`-like, thus the result is an NxN array of all possible sums. Then, we clip it.  We get a 2dim array that satisfies: `c[i,j]=min(i+j,255)` for each i,j.

Then what's left is using fancy indexing the grab the right values. Working with the input you provided, we access:

```
c[( [100, 200, 250] , [50, 50, 50] )]
```

The first index-array refers to the 1st dim, and the second to the 2nd dim. Thus the result is an array of the same shape as the index arrays (`(N,)`), consisting of the values `[ c[100,50] , c[200,50] , c[250,50] ]`.

Comment: Did not know about `putmask`, thanks for that! Using that function, I think `a += b` followed by `np.putmask(a, a<b, 255)` should also work?

Comment: @moarningsun I think you are correct. However it relies on overflowing, which I personally don't feel perfectly comfortable with...

Comment: @moarningsun why did you delete your answer? I think it is a decent answer and it works

Comment: That method requires `putmask` to be efficient, which was one of the main points from your answer. So I figured I might as well put it as a comment here.

Comment: I tried your third method and it works perfectly fine. However, could you explain a little bit more, what it does?
I compared the execution time of this third method ('precalculate') with the case were I just use a uint16 array for a, do a+=b and a[a>255]=255. 'Precalculate' takes approximately double the time. But if it is more memory efficient I will be able to do the calculations with large arrays for which I run out of memory with the uint16 approach.

Comment: We had this code some decades ago, but today, it is a shame, a nightmare  if SW-Developers have to assure there will never be a data overflow because if they have to, then it's just a question of time, until it happens and some application reports the bug by killing peoples in a shuttle. It's a shame that the Python Designers do not understand modern Syntax and Compiler topics.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way:

```
>>> a = np.array([100, 200, 250], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> b = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> a+=b; a[a<b]=255
>>> a
array([150, 250, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: This works because an overflow will be like making a number negative. 
200 + 100 => 44 because 200 is 56 away from 256(=0) so -56+100 = 44. So the result will always be smaller than b if an overflow happened.

Answer (score 5):

How about doing

```
>>> a + np.minimum(255 - a, b)
array([150, 250, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

in general getting the max value for your datatype with

```
np.iinfo(np.uint8).max
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it does, but of dtype uint8, not uint16. However, it creates *three* temp uint8 arrays..

Comment: @shx2: I only count two. `255 - a`, and `np.minimum(255 - a, b)`. What's the third?

Comment: @user2357112, the `a + ...`. If OP wants the result in place of the `a` array, it is possible to avoid that.

Comment: I found this answer to be the fastest for my image (`uint8`) additions

Answer (score 2):

You can do it truly inplace with Numba, for example:

```
import numba

@numba.jit('void(u1[:],u1[:])', locals={'temp': numba.uint16})
def add_uint8_inplace_clip(a, b):
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        temp = a[i] + b[i]
        a[i] = temp if temp<256 else 255

add_uint8_inplace_clip(a, b)
```

Or with Numexpr, for example:

```
import numexpr

numexpr.evaluate('where((a+b)>255, 255, a+b)', out=a, casting='unsafe')
```

Numexpr [upcasts](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide#casting-rules) `uint8` to `int32` internally, before putting it back in the `uint8` array.

Answer (score 2):

```
def non_overflowing_sum(a, b)
    c = np.uint16(a)+b
    c[np.where(c>255)] = 255
    return np.uint8( c )
```

it trades memory too but I found more elegant and the temporary uint16 is freed after conversion on return

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has such a function: cv2.addWeighted

Answer (score -1):

There's [a function in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) for this:

`numpy.nan_to_num(x)[source]`

> Replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers.
>
> Returns an array or scalar replacing Not a Number (NaN) with zero, (positive) infinity with a very large number and negative infinity with a very small (or negative) number.
>
> New Array with the same shape as x and dtype of the element in x with the greatest precision.
>
> If x is inexact, then NaN is replaced by zero, and infinity (-infinity) is replaced by the largest (smallest or most negative) floating point value that fits in the output dtype. If x is not inexact, then a copy of x is returned.

I'm not sure if it will work with uint8, because of the mention of floating point in the output, but for other readers, it may be useful

Comment: I don't see how this could help with the question. There are no NaNs or infinite values in any of the arrays that shall be added. So maybe I'm missing the point of your answer?

Comment: @Thomas hmm, perhaps it is different for integer types, but when I encountered the problem with floats, the overflows appeared as +/- infinities

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Yes, it is indeed different for integers, they simply overflow as in the example of OP.