# python equivalent math equations giving different results

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

why do these two math equations that should be equivalent sometimes give different results?

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(0, 20):
    q = 90000
    A = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 10))
    x = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 1))%2

    s = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 1))
    e1 = np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01, 10)
    e1 = np.array([e1])


    print((A.T.dot(s)+e1.T).T.dot(x))
    print(A.T.dot(s).T.dot(x)+e1.dot(x))
    print("\n")
```

This is the code ran with freshly installed python 3.8
[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and [ask].

Comment: Agreeing with Grismar. Assuming that numpy's dot method and plus operators are implemented correctly, the underlying problem is your understanding of the mathematics (or possibly order of operations in Python).  If you *are* sure that you understand the mathematics and Python's order of operations correctly, then you are effectively making a bug report which should be directed elsewhere https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/bugs.html

Comment: it's a coding questions because there's nothing wrong with the mathematics.  If math is wrong, then they should always give different answers instead of just 30% of the time

Comment: Python 3.6.9, Numpy 1.18.1, I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Is your Python/numpy installation 32bit?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco: I don't think it's a bug. It looks like an int32 overflow.

Comment: This is very closely related to [integer overflow in numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970680/integer-overflow-in-numpy-arrays), and [avoid overflow when adding numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611185/avoid-overflow-when-adding-numpy-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

This looks like [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which will happen faster on a 32-bit Python/numpy installation than on a 64-bit one. You're correct, the two mathematical formulas are equivalent, but their corresponding implementations aren't

## Example

Here's a simple int32 overflow example:

```
np.int32(2**31 - 1) + np.int32(1)
# => -2147483648
```

Mathematically speaking, `2**31 # 2147483648` should come out.

## Your bug

It's possible to reproduce your problem on 64-bit by specifying `dtype` argument for [`randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(0, 20):
    q = 90000
    A = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 10), dtype=np.int32)
    x = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 1), dtype=np.int32)%2

    s = np.random.randint(0, q, (10, 1), dtype=np.int32)
    e1 = np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01, 10)
    e1 = np.array([e1])

    print((A.T.dot(s)+e1.T).T.dot(x)[0,0])
    print((A.T.dot(s).T.dot(x)+e1.dot(x))[0,0])
    print("\n")
```

As an example:

```
2207700288.9948306
-2087267007.0051694


-1701197217.992026
-1701197217.9920263


1592225479.9864094
1592225479.9864097


-2889566938.9977694
1405400357.002231
```

## Solution?

This problem usually doesn't appear with plain Python integers because they are unbounded.

It's hard to propose an effective solution to your problem.

You should avoid formulas with large intermediary results, and you could use `np.int64` instead of `np.int32`. You might still get overflows, but a bit later. See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970697/6419007).

Comment: Interesting. Any insight about which of the 2 math equations uses larger intermediate values and may be more prone to errors? This explains why one or both of the results may be wrong, but not necessarily why they differ from each other